# Python os.popen: How to ensure popen(...) has completed execution before continuing?

Tags: python, multithreading, popen

I have the following code:

```
pwd = '/home/user/svnexport/Repo/'

updateSVN = "svn up " + pwd
cmd = os.popen(updateSVN)

getAllInfo = "svn info " + pwd + "branches/* " + pwd + "tags/* " + pwd + "trunk/*"
cmd = os.popen(getAllInfo)
```

How can I be sure `cmd = os.popen(updateSVN)` has completed execution before `cmd = os.popen(getAllInfo)` begins execution?

Comment: You should use `subprocess.call()` instead.

Comment: Seconding chepner's comment - subprocess.call (or subprocess.check_call) is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
import glob
pwd = '/home/user/svnexport/Repo/'

updateSVN = ["svn", "up", pwd]
cmd = subprocess.Popen(updateSVN)
status = cmd.wait()

# the same can be achieved in a shorter way:
filelists = [glob.glob(pwd + i + "/*") for i in ('branches', 'tags', 'trunk')]
filelist = sum(filelists, []) # add them together

getAllInfo = ["svn", "info"] + filelist
status = subprocess.call(getAllInfo)
```

If you need to capture the subprocesses's output, instead do

```
process = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.stdout.read()
status = subprocess.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to want for the first command to terminate, you don't really need multithreading. You can just do

```
os.system(updateSVN)
os.system(getAllInfo)
```

If you really want to use updateSVN you can wait for it by

```
for _ in cmd:
    pass
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `os.system()` as there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try the wait() method:

```
pwd = '/home/user/svnexport/Repo/'

updateSVN = "svn up " + pwd
cmd = os.popen(updateSVN)
cmd.wait()

getAllInfo = "svn info " + pwd + "branches/* " + pwd + "tags/* " + pwd + "trunk/*"
cmd = os.popen(getAllInfo)
```

Comment: os.wait() only available on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait, the simplest way is to use one of the following *subprocess* functions

- *call*
- *check_call*
- *check_output*

Each one of those returns only after the command execution in the shell completes, see [docs for details](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)